# Responsive table on window resize using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a two column table that I'm trying to transpose at a certain screen size so that they become rows that sit on top of each other. The left column displays a time and the right column displays the content.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>08.30</td>
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>09.30</td>
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>10.00</td>
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried to implement this [technique](http://jsfiddle.net/CsgK9/2/) in a $window.resize function but the table keeps switching as I resize the window. I'm not too hot on jQuery so any help would be much appreciated. Here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tompman/CsgK9/749/).

Many

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/xnJ9Q/ heres an example of it working

Comment: Easiest to accomplish with floating DIVs and media queries. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Divs with flex maybe?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php and the article https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be in a table so a client can edit it in Wordpress otherwise I'd be all over the Divs. I've tried the Responsive tables method above but had problems in IE 9 and below.

Comment: I have made a jQuery plugin for responsive tables, maybe it will help https://github.com/vaskort/respTables

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/veLkf11f/3/  ?

Check the bottom to see how it works:

```
/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
    .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
    .content {text-align:center;}
    .time {text-align:center;}
}
```

Use this tool if you want to get the hang of making your own collapsible column designs: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Hope that helps!
-Joel